# Oracle: Insert a new row based on conditional logic

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I have a table with the following rows and columns

```
id  line  rsn_cd   rsn_amt   svc_cd       svc_dt    AMT_1  AMT_2  AMT_3  AMT_4  AMT_5 
 1    1     XA       15       AB       01/01/2020   10    20      30      40     50
 1    2     XA       15       AC       01/15/2020   0      0      10       0     30
 2    1     XB       10        AX       02/10/2020   35     40     50      12     0
 2    2     XB       10        AZ       02/15/2020   12     51     90      12     0
```

Based on the condition, if RSN_AMT IS NOT NULL and RSN_CD = XA, I have to insert a new line having line number = 100. If RSN_AMT IS NOT NULL and RSN_CD = XB, I have to insert a new line having line number = 200. Below is the result I want. The amounts from AMT_1 to AMT_5 must be set to 0 and svc_cd must be null. The svc_dt in new record must have the latest line svc_dt for a given id.

```
id  line  rsn_cd   rsn_amt   svc_cd       svc_dt    AMT_1  AMT_2  AMT_3  AMT_4  AMT_5 
 1    1     XA       15       AB       01/01/2020   10    20      30      40     50
 1    2     XA       15       AC       01/15/2020   0      0      10       0     30
 1   100    XA       15       null     01/15/2020   0      0       0       0     0
 2    1     XB       10        AX      02/10/2020   35     40     50      12     0
 2    2     XB       10        AZ      02/15/2020   12     51     90      12     0
 2    200   XB       10        null    02/15/2020    0      0      0       0     0
```

Please help me how to figure out this one, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple of `INSERT` statements:

```
insert into my_table (
  id, line, rsn_cd, rsn_amt, svc_cd, svc_dt, 
  AMT_1, AMT_2, AMT_3, AMT_4, AMT_5
)
select
  id, 100, rsn_cd, rsn_amt, null, 
  (select max(b.scv_dt) from my_table b where b.id = a.id),
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
from my_table a
where rsn_amt is not null and rsn_cd = 'XA';
```

And:

```
insert into my_table (
  id, line, rsn_cd, rsn_amt, svc_cd, svc_dt, 
  AMT_1, AMT_2, AMT_3, AMT_4, AMT_5
)
select
  id, 200, rsn_cd, rsn_amt, null,
  (select max(b.scv_dt) from my_table b where b.id = a.id),
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
from my_table a
where rsn_amt is not null and rsn_cd = 'XB';
```